# Accessing model ID in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I’m building my first Backbone application, and I’m a little confused with how I pass an ID into a model. When I instantiate the model, I pass in the ID like this `var user = new UserModel(id);`. At that point, `id == 1`. The value is still the same in the `initialize`
 method in the model. When I use that variable in the `url` property, it’s undefined. Why is that?

```
// Filename: models/user/UserModel.js

define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {

    var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function(id) {
            console.log('modelID: ' + id); // Prints 'modelID: 1'
            this.set({'id': id});
        },
        // Sends GET request to http://[domain]/users/view/undefined
        url: 'users/view/' + this.id
    });

    return UserModel;

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works:

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function(id) {
            console.log('modelID: ' + id); // Prints 'modelID: 1'
            this.set({'id': id});
       },
    // Sends GET request to http://[domain]/users/view/undefined
    url: function(){
        return "/users/view/"+this.get("id");
    }
   });
console.log(new UserModel("10").url())
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wyA9Q/2/

Comment: Right, but how do I make `url` send a GET request to users/view/1?

Comment: Sorry missed that. You could make use the function form.

Answer (score 1):

- A [Backbone model](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor) expects an object representing the attributes as first argument to its constructor

  > **constructor / initialize** new Model([attributes], [options])
  >   When creating an instance of a model, you can pass in the initial values of the attributes, which will be set on the model. If you define an initialize function, it will be invoked when the model is created.
- Setting [model.urlRoot](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot) will help build your URLs

  > **urlRoot** model.urlRoot or model.urlRoot()
  >   Specify a urlRoot if you're
  >   using a model outside of a collection, to enable the default url
  >   function to generate URLs based on the model id. "[urlRoot]/id"
- Attributes should be accessed via `model.get`

So you could define your model as

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/users/view'
});
```

and instantiate it as `var user = new UserModel({id: id});`

Answer (score 0):

```
var userModel = new UserModel({id: 10});
userModel.fetch();
```

It should work :)